# Can a subclass force a call to a parent class method to be a compiler error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my own Exception which **requires** a String to be given at construction so that string can be passed along to the user at catch time.   Currently, in my code I'm throwing an IllegalArgumentException for the zero argument constructor for my class.   What I'd really like is to be able to do is make it a compiler error to call the zero argument constructor for my subclass, as opposed to calling the zero argument constructor for Exception for example.

Is that possible?

Comment: What happens when the caller passes you a null String or an empty String?

Comment: That's a good question.  In my case, I think I'd rather see "null" or a blank message (and have it be a bug) than have the user miss out on the error because of a code problem.  As I understand things, the right way to handle that would probably be IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, don't provide a default constructor, then you can't call it. (Assuming you have another constructor)

Comment: Oh, I thought you would just get the parent class' version in that case.  Thanks!

Comment: constructors don't follow inheritance. The default constructor will call a default constructor of the parent, but that all.